# 거래처 possible meanings

Tags: vocabulary

I have a question about possible meanings of 거래처. In my textbook, it's defined as "client", but from the example sentence below, it seems like it can refer to a place as well.

> 빨리 갑시다. 거래처에서 손님이 이미 도착해 있을 거예요.

Could someone help provide the different contexts that 거래처 can be used?

Comment: The Sino-suffix “-처 (處)” indicates a place, and “거래처” refers to a place by definition. “거래처” meaning “client” is a _derived_ sense of the word.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence you quote, “거래처” is translated as “client”. The sentence translates to “Let’s hurry. The guest from the cliet organization will have arrived.”

So while you are correct “거래처“ can sometimes and rarely used to refer to a physical place, your example sentnece is not an example of that usage.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer mentioned, 거래처 means a place where you do exchange. In your example:

> 빨리 갑시다. 거래처에서 손님이 이미 도착해 있을 거예요.

거래처 means a place you do some sort of business with. In Korea, most people use 거래처 to refer a place (not a person) so they say "I am going to 거래처" or "I need to go meet A from 거래처"

Hope this helped!